# Assumable role in an AWS cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

Using AWS, I'm building a [cloud formation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html) stack defining the following:

1. Several resources (for the sake of simplicity, not transcribed below)
2. A Policy called `MyPolicy` allowing to use those resources (for the sake of simplicity, not transcribed below)
3. A Role called `MyRole` submitted to that policy

The stack will be created by an admin ; and once created, the goal is to allow (from outside the stack) some users to assume `MyRole` in order to use the several resources.

**My question:** How should the role be defined in order be assumable by users (specific users would be allowed from outside the stack) ?

In AWS help page, they give an [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-templateexamples) where `"Service": [ "ec2.amazonaws.com" ]`, meaning that *an* `ec2` instance is allowed to assume that rôle... But I don't understand how it translates to users, and no example is given regarding that scenario.

Below is my stack definition using `JSON` format:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
    "Resources" : {
        "MyRole" : {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "RoleName": "MyRole",
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": { "Service": [ "??" ] },
                        "Action": [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "ManagedPolicyArns": [ { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "MyPolicy", "Arn" ] } ],
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is a little unclear. What do you mean by "in order be assumable by users"? Do you want to give permissions for a stack to be created where users might not have the necessary permissions to deploy those resources themselves, or are you trying to give permissions to use the resources after they have been created? Please edit your question to provide more details and give an example of what you would like them to be able to do that they wouldn't be able to do without such a configuration.

Comment: If you're asking how to specify an IAM user as a Principal in an IAM role then see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Good question! Simply use your root user ARN as the principal. This will allow you to control which user can assume the role using IAM. Here's an example (in YAML for my own sanity):

```
  AdministratorRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: administrator
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            AWS: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:root
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
          Condition:
            Bool:
              aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent: 'true'
      Path: "/"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess

  AssumeAdministratorRolePolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyName: "AssumeRolePolicy-Administrator"
      Description: "Assume the administrative role"
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
        - Sid: "AssumeAdministratorRolePolicy"
          Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
          - "sts:AssumeRole"
          Resource: !GetAtt AdministratorRole.Arn

  AssumeAdministratorRoleGroup:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Group
    Properties:
      GroupName: "AssumeRoleGroup-Administrator"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - !Ref AssumeAdministratorRolePolicy
```

Only thing left is to add user to the *AssumeRoleGroup-Administrator* group.

Bonus: I've added a condition to only allow users that have logged using MFA to assume the role.

Also, just swap your `${AWS::AccountId}` for another account ID you own and you can cross-account assume roles easily.

Answer (score 0):

Let says you want Account `B` can assume the Role to Access Account `A` to have custom list S3 access and AWS managed Rout53 Full access:

Then use Account `A` for the CloudFormation below:

```
Parameters:
  AccountBId:
    Type: String

  environment:
    Type: String
    Default: development
    AllowedValues:
      - development
      - production

Resources:

# Account A:   

  ListS3Access:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
          - "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
          - "s3:ListBucket"
          - "s3:ListBucketVersions"
          - "s3:GetObject"
          Resource: '*'



  TestRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Description: Test Role
    DependsOn:
      - ListS3Access
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            AWS: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AccountBId}:root'
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - !Ref ListS3Access
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonRoute53FullAccess
      Tags:
        - Key: environment
          Value: !Ref environment
```

After you run the Account `A` cloudformation, you should get the `TestRole` arn, save it for Account `B` later usage

On the Account `B` for the CloudFormation Below:

```
Parameters:
  AccountAId:
    Type: String

  roleName:
    Type: String
    Default: xxxxxxxxx 
Resources:
  AssumeTestRolePolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      Description: "Assume My Test role"
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
        - Sid: "AssumeTestRolePolicy"
          Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
          - "sts:AssumeRole"
          Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AccountAId}:role/${roleName}'

  AssumeTestRoleGroup:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Group
    DependsOn:
      - AssumeTestRolePolicy
    Properties:
      GroupName: "AssumeRoleGroup"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - !Ref AssumeTestRolePolicy
```

when you run the Account `B` cloudFormation, give the `TestRole` Arn you got from Account `A`, and provide it to `roleName`

After both cloudFormation has been deploy, login to Account `B`, assign the user to the group, and you should be able use the user to switch the Role.